# Traveling to Schengen Area with a new passport

Tags: schengen, passports

I'm traveling to the Schengen area again within the 180 day period. I have already spent 50 days within the area but have returned back to the States. However, upon returning, my passport was stolen and I've been reissued a new passport. Because I have a new passport, there's no record of me being in the Schengen area in the actual passport itself. Is it possible to overstay the 40 days that I have left for the 90/180 day rule? I want to travel for longer but I only have 40 days left in the area.

Comment: The rule is not bound to your passport, but to your person.  Without your old passport, you may be more likely to escape detection, but do you really want to have that worry hanging over you while you're traveling?

Comment: But be sure you're counting right.  If you spend 50 consecutive days and then leave for at least 90 days, you can actually stay for 90 consecutive days on your second entrance despite the fact that you've entered less than 180 days after your first entrance, because the calculation is done with a rolling 180-day period.